# Java (dice roll deciding who goes first in a snakes and ladders game )

Tags: java

I am developing a snakes and ladders game. I'm having trouble to include a dice roll that determines which player goes first before the game starts.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is what I have attempted:

```
Random rand = new Random();
      int result = rand.nextInt(3); // a random number, either 0 or 1, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)
      if (result == 0) {
           Player 1 goes first
      }
      else {
           Player 2 goes first
      }
```

Comment: Please use the formatting tools to format your code.  What exactly is the problem?  What are you seeing and what are you expecting?   Why are you using 3 as the argument for `rand.nextInt()`?

Comment: There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are off by 1 when you generate a random number.

```
result = rand.nextInt(2) //will return 0 or 1
```

You can create an ArrayList to hold all the rolls, then create a temporary arraylist to hold the rolls. Sort the temp list to get the max value, and then find the index of the max value in the original list.

If you also store your players in an array or list you can use the index you just found to determine which player had the max value

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   roll.add(rand.nextInt(n+1));// this will add n random integers to the arraylist

ArrayList<Integer> tmp = roll;
tmp.sort(null);
int index = roll.indexOf(tmp.get(n));
```

Comment: sorry mate im new to this i havent asked questions before on stack overflow and still trying to understand how to use it

Comment: It is ok, the general rule is if you used someone's answer and it worked to mark it as correct. If you still need help you can just ask me in the comments

Comment: thanks alot , i still need some help. im trying to create a way to decide which player goes first before the game starts in a snakes and ladders game. but the player i want to go first is the one with the largest dice roll. i dont want to specify any integers for example if diceRoll <=3 player 1 goes first , if that makes any sense

Comment: You mean you don't want to print out any integers? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: sorry im abit confused myself but what i intially want to acheive is i want the players to each roll the dice before the game starts and the player with the largest dice roll to go first , hopefully that makes some sense in a way

Comment: Ah, I understand. Are you going to have a max of two players? Or will there be more.

Comment: there will be a max of 4 players

Comment: Much appreciated for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

if you are going with max of 4 players then n value would be 2<=n<=4.

```
List<Integer> decideDiceRollingOrder(int n)
{
     ArrayList<Integer> playingOrder=null;
     if(n<=1 || n>4)
        {
         System.out.println("Please check the players count");
          playingOrder=Collection.emptyList(); // for not throwing the null pointer Exception
       }
     else
        {
           Random rand = new Random();
           playingOrder=new ArrayList<Integer>();
           for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
             {
               playingOrder(i,rand.nextInt(n);// n number of players  
             }  

             //Sort the ArrayList for deciding the order 
         }

   return  playingOrder//sorted list;      

}//method
```

I hope this gives you the major idea on the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would do it this way:

```
import java.lang.Math;

int diceRoll = (int) ((6*Math.random())+1);

if(diceRoll <= 3){
    player1 goes first;
}
else{
    player2 goes first;
}
```

Something along those lines. The line: `6*Math.random()` will give you a number 0-5 and the `+1` makes it a dice roll of 1-6 if that is what you're looking for.

Edit to add: forgot to cast it to an int for you. Also, if you want the number to be from 0 to n, just change the number in front of Math.random() to n+1 (example: you want 0 to 100... 101*Math.random). Casting to an int isn't necessary if you give the if/else a range instead of an equality...

Comment: He only needs a 0 or 1

Comment: He said he was using a dice roll and honestly, if he only needs a 0 or 1 he can just change the code to: `2*Math.random()`

Not seeing why that is worth a downvote, but so be it

Comment: much appreciated for your help dustin , another question instead of declaring player 1 and player 2 in the if statement saying if diceroll <= 3 player 1 goes first, is there a way that it can just generate the largest number of all the players dice roll and then decide who goes first? sorry im new to this and im just trying to get my head around it all

Comment: No worries andrew, everyone is new at one point. I am not totally clear on what you mean by _largest number of all the players' dice roll_... you can use `Math.random()` and make several dice rolls for each player, if that is what you mean. So, like: `int p1roll = 2*Math.random(); int p2roll = 2*Math.random();` but you would still need: `if (p1roll > p2roll){ p1roll goes first}else{p2roll goes first}` If you have four people, the if/else statements just need to include all 4 dice rolls `if (p1>p2 && p1>p3 && p1>p4)` etc

Comment: @sbowde4 has a nice implementation, too, but if you are new and don't really understand what his code means, you can do it with simple if/else statements. His works fine, too, but if you implement his, read up on some documentation so you know what it is doing and can replicate it in the future! Good luck.